# How to put a php file into content area

Tags: php

I got a problem i have a website with 4 navigation buttons 1 is my profile and when u go there i can login and then there i have update profile and when i press it it redirects me to update.php and its on a blank site with no head/body/navigaiton bar only the stuff is there to change data so how would i do it that the website stays the same and in content area there would be the options to update profile now when i click on update profile they options to update are in the left top corner..please need help

thats the code from update.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = new User();

if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
}

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {

            try {
                $user->update(array(
                    'name' => Input::get('name')
                ));

                Session::flash('home', 'Your details have been updated');
                Redirect::to('index.php');

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }

    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->name); ?>">

        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        <input type="hidden" name='token' value="<?php echo Token::generate()?>">
    </div>      
</form>
```

and this is my template.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Stylesheet.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper"> 
            <div id="banner">   
            </div>

            <nav id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Domov</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mojprofil.php">Moj profil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pomoč</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="content_area">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">
                <?php include 'index_2.php'; ?>
            </div>

            <footer>
                <p>Vse pravice pridržane.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a button on the page, which would be a submit button and give it a unique name like `input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit Profile"` with a form action php self, then you could wrap your overall code as `if(isset($_POST['edit'])) { edit profile and the profile } else { profile only }`.

Then if you click the edit profile button it will reload the page but with the ability to edit the profile and still show the profile.